# How to integrate GraphView into my project?

Tags: android, integration, android-graphview

So I was looking for a graph solution for my app and I stumbled on [GraphView](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html).

I was looking around on the github and in the source files and I can't seem to find an integration guide. Maybe it's right in front of my face but I can't see it anywhere.

I have never integrated someone elses code into my own before, so if anyone could give me a quick rundown on how to integrate GraphView with my current project, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 1:

1. get the library's jar [from here](https://github.com/downloads/jjoe64/GraphView/GraphView-3.0.jar).
2. copy that jar to the `/libs` folder in the project where you want to use `GraphView`.
3. use it.

Option 2:

1. Get the project from `github` using `git`:

   - move to your favorite directory using git bash
   - execute from `git` `git clone git://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView.git graphView`
   - in `Eclipse` `File`-> `Import...`-> `Android` -/ `Existing Android Code Into Project`(use `Browse` to navigate to the `graphView` folder from your favorite folder of the previous step)
   - right click the project which will use the `GraphView` -> `Properties` -> `Android` -> at the bottom(the `Library` area) use `Add...` to select `GraphView`
   - use it

Comment: in case of import to Eclipse, you need to move all source file from 'java' folder to 'src' folder

Answer (score 5):

GraphView has been added to Maven Central, so Android Studio integration is even easier now.  Just add the following to your build.gradle file and you don't need to download the .jar.

```
dependencies {
    'com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in Android Studio, add this line in your build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/graphview-3.1.jar')
}
```

And don't forget to click on "Sync project with Gradle files".

Answer (score 1):

Answer using android studio:
- download .jar from [from this link](https://github.com/downloads/jjoe64/GraphView/GraphView-3.0.jar)

-add jar file to project->app->libs

-open build.gradle and under dependencies write:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/graphview-3.1.jar')
}
```

after that sync project